# how to use of update operation sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problem with my sqlite update operation, please help me how to fix it
that is my database handler for update data :

```js
public int updateAccountCalc(Accounts accounts) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, accounts.getId());
        values.put(KEY_NAMA, accounts.getNama());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, accounts.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_BB0, accounts.getBB0());
        values.put(KEY_BB1, accounts.getBB1());
        values.put(KEY_BB2, accounts.getBB2());
        values.put(KEY_BB3, accounts.getBB3());
        values.put(KEY_LILA, accounts.getLila());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(accounts.getId()) });
    }
```

and this is code to use it :

```js
db.updateAccountCalc(new Accounts(0, nama.toString(), email.toString(), bb, 0, 0, 0, lila));
```

i have inserted value of bb, but is never updated on sqlite database

Comment: Did you verify a record existed with getId==0 in db

Comment: acc = db.getAccount(0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(bb0),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
thats code to verify

Comment: Are you sure there is a record with id equal to 0, please verify it first